# .NET C# Desktop Application using Flash Shockwave Object to display UI

Tags: c#, .net, actionscript-3, axshockwaveflash

I Develop a software that is based on Microsoft's .NET framework and is written with C#, our interface is developed on Adobe Flash Platform.

The Big issue is that the communication between them is very poor, as far as we know we can only send Strings to each other.

Is there any way that it could send other DATA Types like an Array as long as flash dont need to parse it and do a cast to Array it will be an upgrade.

Considering that we send trough this little bridge a XML with like 4000 lines we really need to upgrade this pipeline.

PS: JSON is not in our plans for very simple reasons, its ultra new at flash platform and we don't want to force our users to upgrade their activeX players to the very last version.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519079/how-should-client-flashswf-communicate-with-server-side-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [Fluorine FX](http://www.fluorinefx.com/). We are using that to send entire .NET objects from .NET to Flex.

Comment: Thank you Jason, it was something exactly like that we were looking for. we're going to build a prototype with Fluorine, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you tell from the C# side whether the player has JSON support or not, and decide the format then?

If you have to resort to a custom format (if it's not XML and not JSON, you need to implement it yourself), you might as well settle with JSON - just implement the decoder.

Comment: tests with non-native JSON decoders were already made and they performs poorly when compared to native XML parser, actually we can check the player version to tooggle between JSON and XML but we use a WCF service that consumes a PROCEDURE from a SQL Server, and this WCF application is shared by a big number of products, so changing the output to JSON isn't that simple.

Comment: You need to convert he WCF-resulting XML to *something*. Where's the bottleneck?

Comment: So anywhere in .NET Environment is easy to change data types, but don't matter how my WCF outputs, the bottleneck is when we're communicating with the ShockWave object, where the only known input way is a plain String.